# Android Studio open failed erofs (read-only file system)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

En mi aplicación obtengo el error:

> open failed erofs (read-only file system)

Este es el codigo:

```
AssetManager am=getAssets();// If this line gives you ERROR then try AssetManager am=getActivity().getAssets();
        InputStream is=am.open("inventario.xls");
        Workbook existingWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
        WritableWorkbook workbookCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("inventario.xls"), existingWorkbook);
        WritableSheet sheetToEdit = workbookCopy.getSheet(0);
        WritableCell cell;
        Label l = new Label(16,0,"Cotejar");
        cell = (WritableCell) l;
        sheetToEdit.addCell(cell);
        workbookCopy.write();
        workbookCopy.close();

        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilesDir(),"inventario.xls"));
        existingWorkbook.getCell("");
        fo.close();
```

manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: Bienvenido Leonel , agrega más información a tu pregunta, que permisos tienes definidos, y que sistema operativo usas. Revisa [ask] , saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asegúrate que en el **manifest.xml**  estás agregando los permisos de escritura, lectura y por consecuente concederlos en el dispositivo que se ejecuta (versión de Android >= 6 ) tu aplicación.

Asegúrate que tu archivo manifest contenga los siguientes permisos:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Edición**

He buscado algo de información [aquí (stackoverflow en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15711268) sobre los posibles causantes de este error.

- El primero fue el mencionado anteriormente,
- el otro es qué puede ser que estés tratando de guardar información dentro del directorio de la aplicación, si el dispositivo que corres tu aplicación no tiene acceso como super usuario es muy probable que no te permita escribir en dicho directorio.

Prueba usar el método **getExternalFilesDir(null)** en vez de **getFilesDir()**,

```
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),"inventario.xls"));
```

si el problema persiste intenta usar el directorio de Android por defecto con

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Comment: Si el dispositivo tiene OS > 6 no es suficiente agregarlos a el Manifest.

Comment: @Elenasys por eso dije lo siguiente: "y por consecuente concederlos en el **dispositivo** que se ejecuta (versión de Android >= 6 ) tu aplicación."

Comment: si tengo esos permisos en mi manifest.xml y hago las pruebas en un OS 6 y 8

Comment: ¿Y ya los concediste? Sino lo has hecho ve a tus Ajustes>Aplicaciones>tu_aplicacion>Permisos y concede los permisos que necesitas. Pero una solución más adecuada es conceder permisos en tiempo de ejecución: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=es-419

Comment: Si ya los concedi

Comment: Me funciono el `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` muchas gracias.

Comment: @leonelmartinez si la respuesta fue de ayuda marcala con un voto positivo para que otros usuario que tengan la misma  duda puedan encontrarla mas fácilmente. Me alegra haberte ayudado.